# Jquery or Javascript: How to find all html elements which has image more than 500px and less than 2000px?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to find all html elements with jquery or javascript which has image more than 500px and less than 2000px.
Here is my code.

```
$("*").each(function() {
        var image = jQuery(this);
        if ((image.attr("width") >= 512) && (image.attr("width") <= 2048)){
            //do something
        }
    }
```

But with this code I can only find img tag and also which we give width static.
Ex:  working
     not working
And also I can't find div elements or something.
I want to find all html elements which has image where we see width is more than 500px and 2000px.
For example: `<div class="back_img"></div> css: .back_img{background-image:url("img/img.png")}`
I want to find this also.
Is there anybody who knows solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$("*").each(function() {
        var image = jQuery(this);
        if ((image.width() >= 512) && (image.width() <= 2048)){
            //do something
        }
    }
```